# Importing SVG from static resources

Tags: lightning-web-components, svg

I have tried to import a custom SVG into my aura component using an LWC helper component [as described in the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_svg_in_component).

But the final output of the component is something like

```
<use xlink:href="#httpssandbox1examplecs100forcecomcustomersresource1586165694000exampleiconhome"></use>
```

As you can see, it does some sort of sanitation to the Url whithin the `xlink:href` attribute. It does work with the `src` attribute of an `img` tag though.

I am at a loss to explain this behaviour. Any clues?

Michael